# LoginView Not Updating After User Login

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET Membership in order to manage a website users. But without using the specific 'Login Controls'. Actually, just applying Membership class methods in order to Create a user account and also to User login.
On the other hand, there is a LoginView control in Site.Master which is responsible to 'Welcome Username' task.
The problem is that, the LoginView control isn't updated after creating new account or any login.
Do I have to Definitely  use the specific login controls?

----Also, I have set the Login Button CommandName to 'Login'!
----Should I set something like that for Create User Button?

I would appreciate any help...

The following is my code for login:

```
if (!Membership.ValidateUser(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtUserName.Text), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtPass.Text)))
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Invalid user name and password.";
            lblResult.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
```

And here the registration code:

```
MembershipCreateStatus statusUser;

        try
        {
            Membership.CreateUser(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtUserName.Text), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtPass.Text), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtEmail.Text), ddlSexQues.SelectedValue != "-1" ? ddlSexQues.Text : string.Empty, txtSecAnsw.Text == string.Empty ? string.Empty : txtSecAnsw.Text, true, out statusUser);

            txtEmail.Text = string.Empty;
            txtPass.Text = string.Empty;
            txtRepass.Text = string.Empty;
            txtSecAnsw.Text = string.Empty;
            txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
            ddlSexQues.SelectedValue = "-1";

            lblRsl.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblRsl.Text = "حساب کاربری شما با موفقیت ایجاد شد.";
            lblRsl.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (MembershipCreateUserException error)
        {
            lblRsl.Text = GetErrorMessage(error.StatusCode);
            lblRsl.Visible = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using your own login code, you'll need to persist the user's authentication information, for instance by adding a cookie to the response. The built-in controls do this automatically.

I'm assuming you're using Forms-based authentication. There's a reference to the .NET security class for Forms auth here, which details what options are available to you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Look at the `SetAuthCookie` and `RedirectFromLoginPage` methods in particular.

As far as I'm aware, the `CommandName` property is for distinguishing between Button controls in code. As you're using your own methods to handle user creation, I don't think you need to add it to your own control. More here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @AliAshoori - you're welcome. If my answer helped, please consider upvoting it and/or accepting it.